# (TypeError): Blob is not a constructor

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

This code when called under Firefox/Windows it works fine, however, when called from Firefox/Linux it throws the error below:

```
private native String getBlobUrl(String b64)/*-{
    function base64ToBlob(base64) {
        var binary = atob(base64);
        var len = binary.length;
        var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
        var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                view[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var blob = new Blob([ view ]);
        return blob;
    };
    var newBlob = base64ToBlob(b64);
    var URLObj = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var source = URLObj.createObjectURL(newBlob);
    return source;
}-*/;
```

**Error:**

> 00:06:08.107 [ERROR] Uncaught exception escaped
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Blob is
>   not a constructor     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
>     at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)    at
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor73.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

What could be wrong in my code?

I think the error is within this line (yet it works fine under Windows environment):

```
var blob = new Blob([ view ]);
```

Comment: I guess the problem is here: var URLObj = window.URL || window.webkitURL; This reads only from window environment!!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, what is the counterpart code for this in the Linux environment?

Comment: I am not much into java script, so i guess you are now on your own. You can try searching how do you exactly implement this thing in linux instead of the counterpart code for linux :-)

Comment: Actually I think the error is in this line: var blob = new Blob([ view ]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gwt jsni methods you need to use "$wnd." prefixes instead of "window.". Note, that atob() is actually window.atob(). You need to add this prefix for all window.xxx methods in your jsni code (before "atob(base64)", "URL" and "webkitUrl") :

```
private native String getBlobUrl(String b64)/*-{
    function base64ToBlob(base64) {
        var binary = $wnd.atob(base64);
        var len = binary.length;
        var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
        var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            view[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var blob = new Blob([ view ]);
        return blob;
    };
    var newBlob = base64ToBlob(b64);
    var URLObj = $wnd.URL || $wnd.webkitURL;
    var source = URLObj.createObjectURL(newBlob);
    return source;
}-*/;
```

Good article about jsni:
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html

Comment: I added $wnd.atob(base64); but still the same

Comment: What is your version of firefox on linux machine?

Comment: Firefox 10 and Ubuntu Lucid (10.04)

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob Blob constructor is only available from Firefox 13

Comment: You need to upgrade your firefox.

Comment: Ok this answer it then